# FIne tuning query to remove subquery to joining conditions

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join, inner-join

I have been working on fine tuning a query that has multiple subqueries. The subqueries are of from same table but based different filter and sum of column value like below

```
select o.purshase, o.year,o.item,o.period,
    (select sum(value) from tab_a where purchase = o.purchase and year = o.year and item = o.item and period = o.period and type = 'I') as I,
    (select sum(value) from tab_a where purchase = o.purchase and year = o.year and item = o.item and period = o.period and type = 'A') as A
from tab_a o
```

I have tried to move the subquery to the joining condition as below but not getting the same sum(value) output as the above :

```
select o.purshase, o.year,o.item,o.period,
    (select sum(I.value)  ) as I,
    (select sum(A.value)) as A
from tab_a o
left outer join tab_a I on  I.purchase = o.purchase and I.year = o.year and I.item = o.item and I.period = o.period and I.type = 'I'
left outer join tab_a A on  A.purchase = o.purchase and A.year = o.year and A.item = o.item and A.period = o.period and A.type = 'A'
```

I cannot us inner join as type null values are also there which needs to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Without the database it's hard to test, but give a try to this :

```sql
SELECT
    o.purchase,
    o.year,
    o.item,
    o.period,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'I' THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) AS I,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'A' THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) AS A
FROM
    tab_a o
    LEFT JOIN tab_a t ON o.purchase = t.purchase
        AND o.year = t.year
        AND o.item = t.item
        AND o.period = t.period
GROUP BY
    o.purchase,
    o.year,
    o.item,
    o.period
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions rather than subqueries; the trick is to turn the `type` filtering to a conditional expression.

A (quite) database-agnostic way to phrase this would be:

```
select t.*,
    sum(case when type = 'I' then value else 0 end) over(partition by purchase, year, item, period) as i,
    sum(case when type = 'A' then value else 0 end) over(partition by purchase, year, item, period) as a
from tab_a t
```

The upside of this approach is that it scans the table only once, while your original code typically involves 2 scans for each row (one per subquery).